# Guzzle with Laravel send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded request

Tags: laravel, post, postman, guzzle

I keep getting this error when doing a POST request with Guzzle in Laravel:

```
{
data: {
error: "invalid_client"
}
}
```

I am 100% sure the ID's and secrets are correct, because it's working in Postman. This is my code.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        try {
            $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://example.com', [

                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => '*',
                    'client_id' => '*',
                    'client_secret', '*',
                    'scope' => '*',
                    'connector' => '*',
                    'api_token' => '*',
                ]

            ]);

            $res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            dd($res);


        } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

            return response()->json(['data' => $result]);

        }
```

Can anyone please help me out? I also tried with this header:

```
 'headers' => [
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    ],
```

This is the working Postman code. This is working fine. Maybe anyone can see what might be missing in the Guzzle?

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "*",
        "name": "Test",
        "schema": "*"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Add Outbound Invoice",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "value": "Bearer [ACCESSTOKEN]",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\r\n  \"number\": \"test1\",\r\n  \"subject\": \"Test\",\r\n  \"paymentMethod\": \"Online\",\r\n  \"paymentID\": \"onlinePaymentId\",\r\n  \"date\": \"2020-02-13T15:57:41.342Z\",\r\n  \"dueDate\": \"2020-02-13T15:57:41.342Z\",\r\n  \"currency\": \"EUR\",\r\n  \"remarks\": \"Test comments\",\r\n  \"customer\": {\r\n   \"identifier\": \"test@test.net\",\r\n   \"name\": \"George W. Bush\",\r\n   \"addressLine_1\": \"White House\",\r\n   \"zipCode\": \"54623\",\r\n   \"city\": \"Washington\",\r\n   \"countryCode\": \"US\",\r\n   \"emailAddress\": \"test@test.net\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"lines\": [\r\n   {\r\n    \"description\": \"Test Item 1\",\r\n    \"quantity\": 1,\r\n    \"lineAmount\": 10,\r\n    \"lineVATAmount\": 2.1,\r\n    \"product\": {\r\n     \"identifier\": \"testItem1\",\r\n     \"description\": \"This is a test item\",\r\n     \"salesPrice\": 20,\r\n     \"vatType\": \"High\",\r\n     \"vatPercentage\": 21,\r\n     \"glAccountCode\": \"80000\"\r\n    }\r\n   }\r\n  ]\r\n}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "example.com",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "api",
                        "yukiconnector",
                        "nl"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "SalesInvoice"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get Token",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                    "user-agent": true,
                    "accept-encoding": true,
                    "connection": true
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "*",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_id",
                            "value": "*",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_secret",
                            "value": "*",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "*",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "connector",
                            "value": "*",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "api_token",
                            "value": "*",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "   https://example.com",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "auth",
                        "yukiconnector",
                        "nl"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "identity",
                        "connect",
                        "token"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This, It is working fine with me

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://example.com', [
    'headers' => ['Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => '*',
            'client_id' => '*',
            'client_secret' => '*',
            'scope' => '*',
            'connector' => '*',
            'api_token' => '*',
        ],
        'timeout' => 20, // Response timeout
        'connect_timeout' => 20, // Connection timeout
    ]);

dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: Keep getting:Client error: `POST https:/example.com/connect/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_client"}

Comment: That is  a response from the server you are trying to call, I think you are missing Authentication data needed for your call but there is no thing wrong with guzzle

Comment: Thanks. I have added the working Postman code. Can you see what might be missing in the Guzzle?

Comment: I am sure there no thing wrong with guzzle, If you can provide me the working data with postman, I will be able to help.

Comment: Please check the code. It's in my main question now.

Comment: What about Authorization in header ? you added to guzzle request ?

Comment: 'headers' => [
                'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'key: Authorization',
                'value: Bearer [ACCESSTOKEN]',
                'type: text'
            ],

This is not working

Comment: 'headers' => [
                'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer [ACCESSTOKEN]',
            ], also not working

Comment: Any idea @Amr Ezzat?

Comment: If you can attach the real working data to try the request.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try the laravel Facade around Guzzle?

The steps are as follows:

```
// make sure the composer component is installed in console
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

// don't forget include at top of Controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

// inside function
$response = Http::post('http://test.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Steve',
    'role' => 'Network Administrator',
]);

dd($response->json());
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this working. Undefined class when adding use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; in the controller.

Comment: but you did do the composer require command, right? Maybe you also have to do a composer dump && composer install .. Also this from the documentation of laravel 7, if successfully used it there already..

Comment: Yes I did run the composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle. Using laravel 5.6

Comment: Oh Ok, than it won't work. That laravel wrapper didn't exist back then

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Stupid typo. Was missing the '=>' at the 'client_secret'.